# Is there a cross-browser workaround to missing support for RTL is SVG in IE11/Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge, right-to-left

I've ran into what I think is [this bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/101323/) in IE11/Edge.

Here's some SVG to repro it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="168" height="84" direction="rtl">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fff" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="2" height="18" width="164" fill="#ccc" stroke="#333" stroke-width="2"></rect>

    <g transform="translate(161, 14)">
        <text x="0" y="3" width="164">HEADER</text>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(0, 29)">
        <circle cx="150" cy="10" r="15" fill="#aaa"/>
        <g transform="translate(131, 16.8)">
            <text>
                <tspan>Text</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(159, 36.4)">
            <text>
                <tspan>عربى: </tspan>
                <tspan font-weight="bold">A</tspan>
                <tspan>، </tspan>
                <tspan font-weight="bold">B</tspan>
            </text>

            <g transform="translate(0, 14)">
                <text>
                    <tspan>عربى: </tspan>
                    <tspan font-weight="bold">C</tspan>
                    <tspan>، </tspan>
                    <tspan font-weight="bold">D</tspan>
                </text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

See the image below to see the problem (IE11 left, Chrome right, disregard the different zoom levels).

[image]

IE seems to completely ignore the `direction` attribute in the root `svg` tag. As a proof of that, try to remove the attribute and reload the svg in Chrome, and you'll get the same wrong result as IE.

Is a cross-browser workaround to missing support for RTL is SVG in IE11/Edge?

Comment: What do you have in the web document root element? <html lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" dir="rtl">. For mixed language content you can specify the language and direction attributes on the parent phrase elements (svg:text). Language and direction are inherited... looks like Edge does not recognise the svg direction attribute. Remember your svg is embedded in a (x)html document.outcomes may vary from browser to browser.. Also consider that SVG Editors like Adobe include proprietary attribution. I have to reboot so will post back later with a full answer and code. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>SVG Direction tests</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
            <rect height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
            <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fff" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="2"></rect>
            <rect x="2" y="2" height="18" width="164" fill="#ccc" stroke="#333" stroke-width="2"></rect>

            <g transform="translate(161, 14)">
                <text x="0" y="3" width="164" direction="ltr">HEADER</text>
            </g>

            <g transform="translate(0, 29)">
                <circle cx="150" cy="10" r="15" fill="#aaa" />
                <g transform="translate(131, 16.8)">
                    <text direction="ltr" xml:lang="en">
                        <tspan>Text</tspan>
                    </text>
                </g>
                <g transform="translate(159, 36.4)">
                    <text>
                        <tspan direction="rtl" xml:lang="ar">عربى: </tspan>
                        <tspan direction="ltr" xml:lang="en" font-weight="bold">A</tspan>
                        <tspan direction="rtl" xml:lang="ar">، </tspan>
                        <tspan direction="ltr" xml:lang="en" font-weight="bold">B</tspan>
                    </text> 

                    <g transform="translate(0, 14)">
                        <text>
                            <tspan direction="rtl" xml:lang="ar">عربى: </tspan>
                            <tspan direction="ltr" xml:lang="en" font-weight="bold">C</tspan>
                            <tspan direction="rtl" xml:lang="ar">، </tspan>
                            <tspan direction="ltr" xml:lang="en" font-weight="bold">D</tspan>
                        </text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: browser rendering comparison]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this is not enough. The Arabic text should appear on the right of the latin letters, and the positions are off. The desired appearance is the one that Chrome renders in my question. I'm starting to think that there is no cross-browser solution around this bug.

Comment: "The Arabic text should appear on the right of the latin letters, and the positions are off." - well move it in your svg.... svg IS NOT HTML, elements are 'drawn' on the svg canvas with a virtual pen or brush, position and layout are specified by the x/y attributes  relative to the transform of parent <g> elements. Silly...

Comment: What are YOUR language and Text Direction settings in chrome? Make sure they match your Windows 10 settings. Changing the input language in Windows 10 (winkey+spacebar) does not change the dir attribute specified in web pages (or svg elements). Edge does not have a setting to change the presentation direction of a web page like desktop browsers like chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that relies on SVG's `foreignObject` tag, which is supported on Edge and the other major browsers, but unfortunately not on IE. Still, it's better than nothing. With some feature detection in Javascript, one can switch between the original solution and this one depending on the case.

Basically, wrap regular HTML `div` tags containing the text inside a `foreignObject` (remember to specify the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="168" height="84" direction="rtl">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%"></rect>
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="#fff" stroke="#aaa" stroke-width="2"></rect>
    <rect x="2" y="2" height="18" width="164" fill="#ccc" stroke="#333" stroke-width="2"></rect>

    <g transform="translate(1, 1)">
        <foreignObject width="166" height="20">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="padding: 0px 5px;">
                HEADER
            </div>
        </foreignObject>
    </g>

    <g transform="translate(0, 29)">
        <circle cx="150" cy="10" r="15" fill="#aaa"/>
        <g transform="translate(1, 1)">
            <foreignObject width="136" height="20">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="padding: 0px 5px;">
                    Text
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(1, 20)">
            <foreignObject width="166" height="40">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="padding: 0px 5px;">
                    عربى: <strong>A</strong> ، <strong>B</strong>
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(1, 35)">
            <foreignObject width="166" height="40">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="padding: 0px 5px;">
                    عربى: <strong>C</strong> ، <strong>D</strong>
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Here's on it renders on Edge.
[image]